# Restart HTML5 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to get a HTML5 video to restart 2 seconds after a click of a button, but can't seem to figure out how to achieve this using jQuery. This is what I have:

```
var ctrlRE = $('#control-restart'),
    vidMain = $('#main-video')[0];

$(ctrlRE).on('click', function() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        vidMain.pause();
        vidMain.currentTime = 0;
        vidMain.play();
    }, 2000);
});
```

On this HTML:

```
<video id="main-video" width="640" height="360" muted preload="auto" playsinline>
    <source src="video/spin-animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="control-restart">
    Restart
</div>
```

But this just seems to play and pause the video, without actually skipping back to the beginning.

Comment: try vidMain.load(); instead of vidMain.currentTime = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```js
function restartVid(videoId) {
 var vid = document.getElementById('videoId');
 vid.currentTime = 0;
 vid.play();
}
```

```html
<video id="videoId" width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<div onclick="restartVid()">Restart</div>
```